# How to fetch user's direct messages with an instagram api and an access token?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, instagram, instagram-api

I have an access token, the validity of which was verified [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/?access_token=&version=v2.5), issued by an Instagram account for which I'd like to fetch direct messages. I tried calling

```
https://graph.instagram.com/v18.0/{user_id}/conversations?access_token={access_token}
```

and I get the response `{'data': []}`, even though the user has active conversations (3 in the last 1 week). I've gotten the `user_id` field through the

```
https://graph.instagram.com/me?fields=id,username&access_token={access_token}
```

endpoint so I assume this is not an issue. I considered that there might be an issue with my access token's app permissions, but on the app's dashboard `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/APP-ID/app-review/permissions/` this

[image]

option looks like the only one related to direct messages, but it doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for. I have researched this for two days and have noticed some implications that this functionality is not even available anymore. Can anyone point me towards solving this, or tell me that this is not something Instagram supports?